# iOS 8 Silent Push Notification doesn't fire didReceiveRemoteNotification method when application not connected to xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have seen too many questions about the silent push notification does not work if the device is not connected to xcode, but I could not find the real answer. 
I'm using Silent APN to start a process in background and then fire a local Push notification

1. Server sends this info:

   ```
   "_metadata" =     {
       bagde = 1;
       pushText = "semeone has sent you a message!!";
       sender = "semeone";
   };
   aps =     {
       "content-available" = 1;
   };
   ```

   And _metadata is customized info to fire the local notification, I did not included badge, pushText.. in aps because I it is a silent push notification.
2. Client should get the info in didReceiveRemoteNotification,

   ```
   -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
   {
   if(application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateActive ){
           if([userInfo[@"aps"][@"content-available"] intValue]== 1) //it's the silent notification
           {
               //start a background task 
               UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier preLoadPNTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                   NSLog(@"Background task to start a process ");
               }];
               //end completionHandler regarding to fetchCompletionHandler
               completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

               // doing my process...... and fire a local notification

               if(preLoadPNTask){
                   NSLog(@"End Background task ");
                   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:preLoadPNTask];
                   preLoadPNTask = 0;
               }
               return;
           }
           else
           {
               NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification it's NOT the silent notification ");
               completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
               return;
           }

       }
   else {
       if(preLoadPNTask){
           NSLog(@"End Background task ");
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:preLoadPNTask];
           preLoadPNTask = 0;
       }
       completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
   }

   }
   ```

It works perfectly fine when the device is connecting to xcode, but when it doesn't, the didReceiveRemoteNotification doesn't start :(

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What task are you performing when the notification is received?

Comment: I'm adding  to NSMutableDictionary the  ID and  the sender, then I sent data to Worklight  [[WL sharedInstance] sendActionToJS:@"silentNotification" withData:dictionary]; and then I release the Local notification  localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge;
    localNotif.alertBody = textAlert;
    localNotif.userInfo = userInfoData;
    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];

Comment: how do you know if the didReceiveRemoteNotification method is called?

Comment: Because I can see in the devices logs this NSLog(@"Background task to start a process "); and it launch the local push notification, but if the device is not connected it does not launch the local push notification

Comment: I have encountered the same situation with you @jan. Can't solve it so far. (iOS 8.1.2)

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I am using Xamarin to build an iPhone app, and on iOS 8.1.x, the DidReceiveRemoteNotification() method is only reliably called when the phone is connected to a computer. Just connecting to a charger is not sufficient. When not connected, the event is only invoked sometimes, with little or no obvious pattern. Further, even non-silent notifications don't always work either, so it is not just a problem with silent ones (which I understand can be rate-limited, although I am not sending enough to break any sensible limit) iOS 7.x does not seem to have the same issu

Comment: I have tested this on iOS 7 and iOS 8 devices. I have encountered the same issue with iOS 8 devices and couldn't figure out what was going on. 
On my iOS 7 device, everything works -- silent notifications are received (with or without xcode). On my iOS 8 device, silent notifications are not received at all (without Xcode). It works 100% with Xcode though. If any of you find a solution, please let me know.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I am convinced you need to go to Apple and shake somebody's hand or bring coffee in, and they then set a flag that allows some hidden flag within the APNS to say "ok, let the app wake up from a push".

It just doesn't work for mere mortal developers. I just created an empty shell of an app, with just push code, fired up a new app in Parse, regular pushes work perfectly. Pushes to a non-running app simply do not work, and everything i have ever read has been addressed. Sigh. Nice idea Apple, but (and i am willing to be wrong) it just doesn't work as described.

Answer (score 0):

What I end up is  a cable USB was cause me some issues apparently every time that I plugged in the iphone device said that "this accessory may not be supported" but it continue working normally , so I replace for a new one, but that not solve my issue, however can be part of this.  so I looked in the code, and I did some changes, after receive 2 o more silent push notification  preLoadPNTask (UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier) was creating many times so I added a validation before it start,

```
if(!preLoadPNTask){
//start a background task 
            UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier preLoadPNTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                NSLog(@"Background task to start a process ");
            }];

 }
```

I hope this help you 
Regards

Comment: Also remember close the preLoadPNTask  (BackgroundTask)  before 3 minutes or the app will be crash

Answer (score 0):

In ios 8,  You need to the following steps to fire didReceiveRemoteNotification: method

1. Select project target goto Capabilities tab
2. Select 'Background modes' turn on.
3. It'll add a key (Required background modes)in your project info.plist

After these modifications, when you get a apple push notification and if the app is in background already then didReceiveRemoteNotification will be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because under iOS 8 you have to ask for push notifications in a different way. Try this:

```
-(void) registerForPushNotifications {

UIApplication* application=[UIApplication sharedApplication] ;

// Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

} else {
    // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

}